# How to detect click on object in Unity3D' SceneView from a custom Editor Window

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

To speed up scene setup, I developed a bunch of custom editors. I want to add a new feature on one of those editor that would detect when an object has been clicked in the SceneView (and thus prevent a selection change, as this editor purpose is to link objects between them).

I managed to achieve that by preventing the default selection and raycasting from the mouse position on the SceneView. My only issue is that when the objects don't have any collider, it won't work (and adding a collider on those objects is out of question). And yet, the editor is capable of detecting clicks on objects without colliders.

All my google-fu brought are "Add a collider" approach (not possible) or a "Do your own raycasting" (a bit overkill to my taste).

Please note that I'm not looking for a workaround, I found a bunch of those already (Bounds.IntersectRay on all scene objects, reverting selection OnSelectionChange, using Selection.gameObjects, etc). I'm really looking for the ideal solution (even if not documented) out of curiosity to get a better understanding of what is possible or not from a custom editor perspective.

Comment: Nice question. It's not clear to me why you can't use OnSelectionChange for this? And, out of curiosity, how do you manage to" preventing the default selection and raycasting from the mouse position on the SceneView"?

Comment: The solution I ended up doing actually uses On SelectionChange. It's just that when I started implementing this, my mind was set on a certain idea, built on how I do that kind of stuff outside of the editor (raycast in OnUpdate, filtered on the specific layer). It's only when I realised that it was not possible to do it without collider (and yet the editor manages to do it somehow) that I got really curious about it. What motivates my question is really more about having a better and deeper understanding of Unity than founding a practical solution.

Comment: On your second question, I used a solution inspired by http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/303248/how-to-paint-objects-in-the-editor.html. Basically, you get the current event in OnSceneGui, and if your conditions are fullfilled, you Event.current.Use() to consume the event and prevent it being forwarded. As the link states, you also have to use HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl(GUIUtility.GetControlID(GetHashCode(), FocusType.Passive)); when the EventType is Layout. In my case, if a certain button is toggled, it would detect click on certain specific object, and links them in the click order